# Problem to integrate Jitsi Meet Sdk with linphone

Tags: android, linphone, jitsi-meet

I am using JItsi meet api for video call on linphone android app open source project. I have followed jitsi meet handbook for integrating on linphone.

Here is my sample code:

```
public class JitsiActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    URL serverURL;
    try {
        serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException("Invalid server URL!");
    }
    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions =
            new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                    .setServerURL(serverURL)
                    .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                    .build();
    JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);

    JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options =
            new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder().setRoom("linphone").build();
    JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, options);
    finish();
}
```

}

I have successfully made a call on debug mode, after making an apk on release mode, It refresh activity when I attempt to make a video call and go to home page. can you give me a guideline to solve this problem. I have tested apk on Android 10 OS.

--After Debugging on release mode I have found this error

020-09-24 16:50:12.383 10364-10364/org.linphone E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: org.linphone, PID: 10364
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: reportSizeConfigurations: ActivityRecord not found for: Token{2329006 ActivityRecord{cf5fae1 u0 org.linphone/.activities.JitsiActivity d-1 s-1 t-1 f}}
at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1967)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1931)
at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1881)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.reportSizeConfigurations(IActivityManager.java:8621)
at android.app.ActivityThread.reportSizeConfigurations(ActivityThread.java:3360)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2043)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7096)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:536)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:928)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.reportSizeConfigurations(ActivityManagerService.java:10305)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact$reportSizeConfigurations$(IActivityManager.java:12560)
at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub.onTransact(IActivityManager.java:2357)
at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:3841)
at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:750)

Comment: `It refresh activity` i.e its probably Crashed . See the logs for Error . And add the Error crash logs with question .

Comment: It works fine on debug mode. But after building release apk, it crushes when attempting to video call that's why I can't see error log. I used whole chunk of code under try catch to see error on toast but it doesn't show any exception either.

Comment: Set debuggable true for release build and then check the logs . No one can help without stack trace .. also mention of you are using any code obfuscation lib like proguard .

Comment: @ADM I have added error log. can you help me now?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a stacktrace to for anyone to help you debug it, however, this code can be simplified greatly which would lead to easier debugging..

You are supplying Jitsi with it's own default server url "https://meet.jit.si" which isn't necessary as Jitsi will use it's own server anyway. If you were planning on using your own server you can still provide that easily in the `JitsiMeetActivity::launch` method as the room parameter...
`JitsiMeetActivity.launch(context, "https://myserver.com/linphone")`

Removing all the unnecessary boiler-plate will leave you with this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    JitsiMeetActivity.launch(this, "linphone");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. This is just only for R&D to make one of our project. Now I have added error log. can you help me now?